# Understanding NumberFormatter for currency in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

I have an app where I'm trying to format a `Double` with `NumberFormetter` but the output I'm getting does not match the output in other apps.

Here is the code I'm using...

```
let price:Double = 25
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current

let priceFormatter = currencyFormatter.string(for: price)

myLabel.text = priceFormatter
```

With the above code and with the phone's `Region`set to China in my App I get `25,00 CNY` but in two other third-party-apps the output is `CN¥25.00`.

What am I doing wrong?

### Region Set to China:

> My App
>   25,00 CNY
>
> Other Apps
>   CN¥25.00

### Region Set to France:

> My App
>   25,00€
>
> Other Apps
>   €25,00

But when the region is set to `United States` I get the same notation in all three (3) apps.

### Region Set to United States:

> My App
>   $25.00
>
> Other Apps
>   $25.00

I'm a little concerned especially with the output when the region is set to China because besides the notation being different I also get a different symbol `CNY` vs `CN¥`.

Any suggestions, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spoiler the other apps are doing it wrong, your output is correct !

Answer (score 3):

You can specify [the format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Currency_Formats) you want the output. Exemple :

```
let number: NSNumber = 25
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "cn_CN") // or "en_US", "fr_FR"
numberFormatter.positiveFormat = "#0.00 ¤"
let price = numberFormatter.string(from: number)
```

which gives the output

> 25.00 CN¥

You can change the format to get different outputs:

> "#0.00 ¤" => 25.00 CN¥
>
> "#0.00 ¤¤" => 25.00 CNY
>
> "#0.00 ¤¤¤" => 25.00 Chinese yuan

Answer (score 2):

It simply depends entirely what you want to do. In short, when presenting results in the user interface, it is a function of the locale of the device, not the currency in question.

For example, if I was displaying ten thousand US dollars exchanged into in euros at today’s exchange rate, you might display `8.950,95 €` on a device with a German locale. Both the number formatting and placement of the currency code would be localized for the device in question, not the currency.

However, if I was showing the same result on a US device, I might present it with customary US number/currency formatting, e.g. perhaps `€8,950.95`.

FWIW, English-language style guides, such as *The Chicago Manual of Style* and *The Economist Style Guide,* confirm this approach. I assume the “preserve the audience’s expectation for foreign currencies” applies in other languages, too.

Bottom line, one should generally format numbers in the user interface in accordance with the device locale, but obviously employ the currency symbol and number of fractional digits in accordance with the currency being represented.